# Change the tint color of the ActionSheet that appears when you long tap on a link in a WKWebView

Tags: swift, ios8, webkit, uiactionsheet, wkwebview

I'm writing an iOS 8 app and this problem is driving me crazy... I've set the tint color of my window in white (because I've got colored toolbar and navigation bar) but now, when in my WKWebView I long press on a Link, the actions titles of the Action Sheet that appears are written in White and so it's very difficult to read them.
Is there a way to change the tint color of this object?

I tried with
UIActionSheet.appearance.tintColor but it doesn't work, perhaps that control is not a UIActionSheet?

Thank you
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution but I've found a workaround: I set the tint color of the window as I like and then I set just the navigation bar's tint color and the toolbar's tint color in white.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, Swift 2.1 xCode 7 :

```
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Launch your GPS navigator", delegate: self, 
                               cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: 
                              "Cancel", otherButtonTitles:"Open path in Google Maps"
                              , "Open path in Maps", "Open path in Waze")
if actionSheet.respondsToSelector("_alertController") {    
    let alertController = actionSheet.valueForKey("_alertController")
    if ((alertController?.isKindOfClass(UIAlertController)) != nil) {
       alertController?.view??.tintColor = UIColor.redColor
    }
}
actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
```